# Error in SQL syntax

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',child_fname,child_sname) AS 'Child Name'
    , child_gender AS 'Gender'
    , child_dob AS 'DoB'
    , COUNT activity_name AS 'Activities name'
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', parent_title, parent_fname, parent_sname) AS 'Parent Name'
    , parent_phone AS 'Parent phone'
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', parent_address1, parent_address2, parent_town,
        parent_county parent_pcode) AS 'Parent Address',
FROM 
    Child,
    JOIN ChildActivity USING(child_id),
    JOIN Activities USING(activity_id),
    JOIN Parent USING(parent_id),
WHERE 
    activity_name='Art';
```

Query browser says I have `error near 'AS Activities name... CONCAT_WS('',...at line 4.`

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL-Server and not MySQL?

Answer (score 11):

There are several problems in your query.

- First, there is no `CONCAT_WS()` function. I assume you want to concatenate the strings. Use the `+` operator instead if you are using SQL-Server:

  ```
  child_fname + ' ' + child_sname AS "Child Name",
  ```

  or if you are using MySQL, the `||` operator or `CONCAT()` function:

  ```
  child_fname || ' ' || child_sname AS "Child Name",
  ```

  or (**Correction, update**), just keep the `CONCAT_WS()` function, it's suitable in your case, if you are using MySQL.
- Second, there are several commas in wrong places (before the `FROM` and and the `JOIN` keywords.
- Third, the aliases should be quoted either with double quotes (like: `"Child Name"`) or brackets (like: `[Child Name]`) or not at all if they have no special characters and are not reserved (like: `Gender`). Don't use single quotes for column or table aliases. Single quotes are for string literals, like `'Art'`. MySQL may allow you to use them in aliases, too, but don't fall into this bad habit.
- Fourth, the `COUNT()` is an (aggregate) function and it needs parenthesis. But since you have no `GROUP BY`, there is no point in using `COUNT()`.
- And last, SQL-Server does not like the `USING` syntax for joins, so use the `ON` instead (which works in all DBMS).

So, the query becomes:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', child_fname, child_sname) AS "Child Name",
    child_gender AS Gender,
    child_dob AS DoB,
    activity_name AS "Activities name",
    CONCAT_WS(' ', parent_title, parent_fname, parent_sname) AS "Parent Name",
    parent_phone AS "Parent phone",
    CONCAT_WS(' ', parent_address1, parent_address2, parent_town, parent_county, parent_pcode)
      AS "Parent Address"                 --<-- Comma removed here.

--- for MySQL
FROM Child                                --<-- Also here
  JOIN ChildActivity USING(child_id)      --<-- and here
  JOIN Activities USING(activity_id)      --<-- and here
  JOIN Parent USING(parent_id)            --<-- and here.

--- for SQL-Server or MySQL
--- FROM Child 
---   JOIN ChildActivity ON ChildActivity.child_id = Child.child_id  
---   JOIN Activities ON Activities.activity_id = ChildActivity.activity_id  
---   JOIN Parent ON Parent.parent_id = Child.parent_id     

WHERE activity_name = 'Art' ;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `USING` either. Though I suspect they have mistagged as when I execute the original query in SQL Server it complains `'CONCAT_WS' is not a recognized built-in function name.` rather than the message given in the OP.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, it's probably in MySQL and the error is from the `COUNT` line.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you so much I really appreciate your answers, they worked perfectly.

Comment: @ypercube Thank you so much i appreciate you answers, you really made my day.